# perl print hex ascii from arg input

Tags: bash, perl, escaping, hex, ascii

I'm piping some hex ascii into perl and would like to use it's print function to print this stuff to a file. however the hex is not printed as ascii but as normal string

```
echo "\x48\x32\x35\x45" "\x90\xc1\xe2\x7a" | perl -e' @string =  split " ",<>; print ${string[0]},chr(0),"$string[1]";' > input.txt
```

This gives however the following in input.txt

```
\x48\x32\x35\x45^@\x90\xc1\xe2\x7a
```

where it should more look like

```
H25E^@<90><C1><E2>z
```

Comment: Is this what you want `echo -en "\x48\x32\x35\x45 \x90\xc1\xe2\x7a"`? Or even `echo -en "\x48\x32\x35\x45 \x90\xc1\xe2\x7a" | cat -A` ?

Comment: Any character codes above 0x7F are not ASCII. Are you saying you want anything less than 0x2o to be displayed as `^@` etc and anything over 0x7E to appear as `<7F>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `eval`s (and extra double quotes) to make perl "interpret" the hex escapes:

```
echo "\x48\x32\x35\x45 \x90\xc1\xe2\x7a" | perl -e '@string = split " ",<>; print eval "\"$string[0]\"",chr(0),eval "\"$string[1]\"";'
```